# Updating Display based on dropdown

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

As part of a form, I need to display some data about an object from a dropdown.  The user using the field is assigning a student to a section of a class, and will need to see the current count of open/filled seats in the class.

Currently, I am building my class drowndown like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sections Available", new SelectList(Model.AvailableSections, "Id", "Name"))
```

and later I want to have a div that lists out the availability like:

```
Open Slots: @someVariable
Filled Slots: @someOtherVariable
```

This information is part of my Sections model that belongs to the VM for this page.  Those look like:

```
public class ApproveStudentViewModel
{
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public List<Section> AvailableSections { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}


public class Section
{
    public Guid Id {get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public int SpacesRemaining {get; set;}
    public int SpacesTaken {get; set;}
}
```

I have a controller call available for getting the section by Id, but that is as far as I've gotten on figuring this out.  I'm very new to using MVC and Razor in particular, and this sort of thing should not be as hard as it is appearing to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by using jQuery if you are open to that.You can then make the jQuery AJAX function create a new Div based on the Section by ID. So changes to your code would be as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SectionsAvailable", new SelectList(Model.AvailableSections, "Id", "Name"))
<div id="slot-information"></div>
```

The at the end of your Razor page you need to make sure that you are referencing jQuery

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Now you can create an AJAX call to your controller function and send the sectionID as a parameter:

```
<script>

$("#SectionsAvailable").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '@Url.Content("~/")' + "{ControllerName/GetSpaceInfo",
        data: { sectionID: $("#SectionsAvailable").val() }, //id of the section taken from the dropdown
        success: function (data) {
            var items = '';

            $.each(data, function (i, row) {
                items += "<label> Open Slots: " + row.SpacesRemaining +  "</label> <label> Filled Slots: " + row.SpacesTaken +  "</label> ";
                //To test in your browser console
                console.log(row.SpacesTaken);
                console.log(row.SpacesRemaining);

            });
            $("#slot-information").html(items);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("oops");
        }
    });
});
```

Finally in your controller (maybe SectionsController) create the following function to return the JSON object.

```
        // returns a list of space available based on section 
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetSpaceInfo(int sectionID)
    {
        List<Section> sect = new List<SSection>();
        //Should only return 1 item to the JSON list
        sect = _context.Sections.Where(m => m.Id == sectionID).ToList();
        return Json(sect);
    }
```

Haven't tested the code but this should do the trick. If it isn't working check the console in your browser.

Comment: It's not firing off any request on change of the dropdown.No network activity and nothing hitting the controller

Comment: I had a rather stupid typo in my ajax call.  Fixed and it is calling everything appropriately.  Thanks